# advanced custom fields and contact form 7

Tags: forms, code, contact

I want to use contact form 7 shortcode in advanced custom fields

I created field called shortcode with advanced custom fields
and put the contact form 7 shortcode in it.
it displayed the form as frontend but no functionality.

I am using the free version of advanced custom fields. also I choose the type of the field as wysewig

then here is the code

```
<?php echo get_field('shortcode'); ?>
```

I used the shortcode of contact form 7 on another page and the form worked well without using advanced custom fields. so what is the wrong, please?

********* after updating *********

```
<form class="getin_form wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="400ms" onsubmit="return false;">
            <?php echo do_shortcode(get_field('shortcode')); ?>

            </form>
```

unfortunately can not send the link because it is on localhost. I am using xampp
but this is the picture of the advanced custom fields shortcode field

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost got it.

You should use the do_shortcode function.

`<?php echo do_shortcode(get_field('shortcode')); ?>`

Comment: thanks so much for your reply. I tried your code, but it still the same problem. please note that I am using the free version of advanced custom fields. also I choose the type of the field as wysewig. is there still something wrong?

Comment: change it to text, only add the shorcode and it should work. wysiwyg sometimes adds html that can create some problems when using shortcodes

Comment: @  Buttered_Toast thanks for your comment. I changed it to text field. but  I am still getting the same problem

Comment: could you please provide a screenshot of the field with the contact form 7, the php code and a link to the page? this could help alot with tracking down the problem. Check the console as well to see what errors you get

Comment: @ Buttered_Toast I just updated my post with the information you asked. please check it

Comment: Remove the form tag, when using the contact form 7 shortcodes they already create the complete form, one of the elements is the form tag

Comment: @ Buttered_Toast   thanks so much. it was very helpful and it works now